# OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable BN_mod_inverse_no_branch error

Tags: openssl, arm, windows-ce, opc-ua

I've compiled OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable(12ad22dd) for WinCE6(x86) and WinCE7(ARMv4I)
by following the steps on this website:
https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkcpp/1.6.0/html/CompileOpenSSLCE.html

(I actually want to build this OPC UA library)

The builds on WinCE6(x86) are correct, but only debug build on WinCE7(ARMv4I) is OK.
Release build on WinCE7(ARMv4I) will crash and the OpenSSL error output shows

```
112525610:error:0308B06C:bignum routines:BN_mod_inverse_no_branch:no inverse:.\crypto\bn\bn_gcd.c:692:
112525610:error:04081003:rsa routines:RSA_BUILTIN_KEYGEN:BN lib:.\crypto\rsa\rsa_gen.c:263:
```

I have no idea about that and also confirmed many times for my compile setting and re-compiled.
Can anyone help me?